# Theme only supports one menu?

Tags: menus

I would like to use the main menu but also have a menu in the footer for things like

about, career, etc.

Am I <strike>fubared</strike> foobared or can I do this?

Comment: Where are you getting the idea that the theme only supports one menu? Does it say that somewhere? What theme is it?

Comment: Hiro please take a moment to read the http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq , you have asked several questions that are localized to a theme shop and will be closed.

Comment: Under Appearance->Menus->Theme Locations...per below this is WP related...let's not be so close happy.

Answer (score 2):

It means that the theme uses `wp_nav_menu` instead of ... wait for it ... `wp_nav_menus`

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menus for the function to use `wp_nav_menus` and be able to configure multiple menus under Dashboard>>Appearances>>Menus

See also http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to use the main menu but also have a menu in the footer for things like
>
> Am I fubarred or can I do this?

Yes, you can.

<sup>Read [the docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus).</sup>